# Assignable r-value

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, rvalue-reference

Why is the following code correct:

```
struct A
{
  A operator+( A const& elem )
  {
    return *this;
  }

  bool operator==( A const& elem )
  {
    return true;
  }

  operator bool()
  {
    return true;
  }
};


int main()
{
  A a_1, a_2;

  if( ((a_1+a_2) = a_1) )
  {}
}
```

Here, I expected an error in the if-statement since `a_1 + a_2` is an r-value. Replacing the line `A a_1, a_2;` by `int a_1, a_2;` leads to the expected error:

```
error: expression is not assignable
      if( ((a_1+a_2) = a_1) )
           ~~~~~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: *Huge* kudos for reducing your problem to such a minimal (but still complete) example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because for the class `A`, `(a_1+a_2) = a_1` will be just parsed as a call to `A::operator=(const A&)` at last. Even what `a_1+a_2` returns is a temporary object, call the member function on it is still valid.

If you want to prohibit such calls on temporary objects, you might use [ref-qualified member functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/member_functions#const-.2C_volatile-.2C_and_ref-qualified_member_functions) (since C++11), which could be used for distinguishing the objects called on are l-values or r-values. e.g.

```
struct A
{
  //...
  A& operator=(const A&) && = delete; // prevent from calling with temporary objects
  A& operator=(const A&) & = default;
};
```

Comment: The hint "ref-qualified member functions" is very good -- thanks.